# How to use gather() in python to return values at specific indices of a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor which looks like this:

```
tensor([[-0.0150,  0.1234],
    [-0.0184,  0.1062],
    [-0.0139,  0.1113],
    [-0.0088,  0.0726]])
```

And another that looks like this:

```
tensor([[1.],
    [1.],
    [0.],
    [0.]])
```

I want to return the values from the first tensor, for each row, that corresponds to the indice from the second tensor.

So our output would be:

```
tensor([0.1234], [0.1062], [-0.0139], [-0.0088]])
```

So far I have this code:

```
return torch.gather(tensor1, tensor2)
```

However I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: gather() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Tensor), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, int dim, Tensor index, *, bool sparse_grad, Tensor out)
 * (Tensor input, name dim, Tensor index, *, bool sparse_grad, Tensor out)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `dim` argument.
You can see an example here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html

For your case I think that `return torch.gather(tensor1, 1, tensor2)` should work

Comment: I have chaned to return tensor1.gather(1, tensor2) which seems to work for other people, yet I am still getting the error: RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

Comment: Try changing tensor2 to ints

Answer (score 0):

```
t2=torch.tensor([[-0.0150,  0.1234],
[-0.0184,  0.1062],
[-0.0139,  0.1113],
[-0.0088,  0.0726]])
t3=torch.tensor([[1.],
[1.],
[0.],
[0.]]).type(torch.int64)
res=t2.gather(1,t3)
print(res)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.